# Restangular Delete with body data

Tags: angularjs, restangular

Below is my restangular delete request where i intend to pass an array of ids to delete based on user selection

```
var deleteIds = [1,5,10]
Restangular.all('url').customDELETE(deleteIds);
```

I want this deleteIds to be passed in body params. How can i send the array as body so tat i could see the request payload.

Answer (score 2):

Actually I also needed to use the delete http method with data passed in the body, and I found that Restangular supports a customOperation

documentation:
https://github.com/mgonto/restangular#custom-methods

> - customOperation(operation, path, [params, headers, elem]): This does a custom operation to the path that we specify. This method is actually used from all the others in this subsection. Operation can be one of: get, post, put, remove, head, options, patch, trace

example:

```
Restangular.all('some/path/123')
    .customOperation('remove', '',{'content-type': 'application/json'},[1,5,10])
```

Comment: params is missing in your example. it should be `Restangular.all('some/path/123')
    .customOperation('remove', '', null, {'content-type': 'application/json'}, [1,5,10])` (note the third parameter with value `null`)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the backend technology you use, the body might be ignored for DELETE requests. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299628/is-an-entity-body-allowed-for-an-http-delete-request) question for more info.

I would suggest you to pass the id's as a part of the url.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.Actually the backend is coded and they dont want to be distrubed for multiple reasons. That's why i got struck. Any other ideas to overcome this.

Comment: Sending body with GET and DELETE action is not advised but still allowed. For example ElasticSearch API supports it.